# Ground overlay performance issue. Must I tile overlay?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlay

This is a pretty basic question, I'd appreciate some high level direction:

I allow a user to upload an arbitrary image, and stretch(and rotate) it over a google map. Practically speaking, this image should be no bigger geographically than a few acres, but it can (and is likely to be) a couple mb.

I'm loading the image to a canvas to do rotation, and then giving that to a ground overlay to stretch and position the image, but for a larger file, (say 1-2 mb plus) it takes a while (2 or 3 seconds) to display after each adjustment. I'm then saving the image and orientation, and loading and placing it without adjustment hooks. It's on this second page that I need it to load more efficiently, since each map move or zoom is causing it to re-render, and takes basically forever each time unless I'm loading something the size of an icon into the overlay.

My question is, how could I best optimize the display of this image on this second page where it's basically read-only? Is a tile overlay setup the only way? would re-saving the image post rotation be likely to help me out? Tile overlay seems complicated to me, so I'm hoping there's another way to speed this up. I appreciate the help.

Here's my overlayImage() function:

```
function overlayImage()
{
var c = document.getElementById("overlayCanvas");
c.width = c.width;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

if (imgoverlay!=null) {imgoverlay.setMap(null);imgoverlay=null;}
var img = new Image();
img.src = overlayurl;
img.onload = function() {

    var dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(neBound.getPosition(), swBound.getPosition()); // distance between the pins

    var ratio = dist / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(img.width,2) + Math.pow(img.height,2)); //ratio between the map units and pixel units on the image

    var ang = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(swBound.getPosition(), neBound.getPosition()); //heading from one pin to the other
    var imgangle = Math.atan(img.width/img.height)*180/Math.PI; //heading for zero rotation (aspect ratio of the image)
    degrees = ang-imgangle; // rotation we need to perform is the difference

    midpoint = nextGeo(swBound.getPosition(), dist/2, ang); //the midpoint of the two pins.

    var boundHeight = ratio * (img.width * Math.abs(Math.sin(degrees * Math.PI/180)) + img.height * Math.abs(Math.cos(degrees * Math.PI/180))); //x sin degrees + y cos degrees, all times ratio
    var boundWidth = ratio * (img.width * Math.abs(Math.cos(degrees * Math.PI/180)) + img.height * Math.abs(Math.sin(degrees * Math.PI/180)));

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        nextGeo(nextGeo(midpoint, boundHeight/2, 180), boundWidth/2, 270), 
        nextGeo(nextGeo(midpoint, boundHeight/2, 0), boundWidth/2, 90)
    );
    console.log(bounds);
    ctx.canvas.width = img.width * Math.abs(Math.cos(degrees * Math.PI/180)) + img.height * Math.abs(Math.sin(degrees * Math.PI/180));
    ctx.canvas.height = img.width * Math.abs(Math.sin(degrees * Math.PI/180)) + img.height * Math.abs(Math.cos(degrees * Math.PI/180));
    ctx.translate( c.width/2, c.height/2 );
    ctx.rotate( degrees*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.translate( -c.width/2, -c.height/2 );
    ctx.drawImage(img, (c.width-img.width)/2,(c.height - img.height)/2);
    console.log(img.width, img.height);
    console.log(c.width, c.height);
    imgoverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(c.toDataURL("img/png"), bounds, {opacity: 1, clickable: false});
    imgoverlay.setMap(map);
};
}
```